# ncclient: connecting to a NETCONF server

Tags: ssh, ietf-netconf

I want use the python library ncclient 0.6.6 with Python 2.7.15 to connect to a NETCONF server (netopeer2) and read out the running config.

I tried to follow the example from the manual, running this code in the console:

```
with manager.connect(host="*the IP adress*", port=*the port*, timeout=None, username="*user*", password="*pwd*") as m:
    c = m.get_config(source='running').data_xml
    with open("%s.xml" % host, 'w') as f:
        f.write(c)
```

As written in the manual, I try to disable public-key authentification with allow_agent and look_for_keys as False. Unfortunately, this does not work properly, because I get the error message:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/sisc/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ncclient/manager.py", line 177, in connect
    return connect_ssh(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/sisc/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ncclient/manager.py", line 143, in connect_ssh
    session.connect(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/sisc/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ncclient/transport/ssh.py", line 481, in connect
    raise SSHUnknownHostError(known_hosts_lookup, fingerprint)
ncclient.transport.errors.SSHUnknownHostError: Unknown host key [e3:8d:35:a9:43:f9:3c:8a:f4:d3:88:5b:a9:36:93:59] for [[192.168.56.2]:1831]
```

I do not get why it still complains about the unknown host key, even though I explicitly disabled public-key authentification.
The netopeer NETCONF server is definitely running, for I get a "Hello" Message as soon as I try to SSH into it from out of the terminal.
Did I miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
m = manager.connect(host="172.17.0.2", port=830, username="netconf", password="netconf", hostkey_verify=False)
```

Did the trick. Hostkey_verify has to be false.